# doPrivileged and java applet sandbox

Tags: java, applet, sandbox

If I use this code in an applet class ,for example ,run it in an applet sandbox

```
public void init() {
    try {
        class doInit implements PrivilegedExceptionAction {

            public Object run() throws Exception{
                File file = new File("/tmp/1.txt");
                FileOutputStream fos = null;

                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fos.write("hello world2".getBytes());
                fos.close();
                return null;
            }
        }
        ;
        doInit di = new doInit();
        AccessController.doPrivileged(di);
```

I know it will fail and throw a security exception.
but why?

`File` and `FileOutputStream`  are in core java API ,but I can not get the permission by using  `doPrivileged`?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of an Applet, you as the developer of the applet are not the one who has the right to grant or revoke privileges.
They are determined by the security settings and policies on the machine where the applet is executed.
One requirement for the applet is to be signed by a valid and trusted certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Further to the answer of @mschenk74:

A trusted applet can read files, whereas a sand-boxed applet cannot (with or without `doPrivilieged`).

But if a method in a trusted applet is called (for example) by JavaScript, the JVM no longer considers it trusted.  **That** is where `doPrivileged` is used.  It effectively says to the JVM 'Consider this code to be trusted, even if called by something else like JS'.

There *is* a way for a non-trusted applet to write a file to local disk, but it involves using the [JNLP API file services](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs).